# Calculating the sum of a series of Lorentzian function

Tags: algebra

I understand the following result.

```
Sum[1/((x + n)^2 + a^2), {n, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> `π Sinh[2 a π])/(a (-Cos[2 π x] + Cosh[2 a π]))`

But if I input

```
Sum[a/((x + n)^2 + a^2), {n, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

where I'm just multiplying the first argument by a factor of `a`, the result is totally different.

> ```
> 1/2 I (PolyGamma[0, 1 - I a - x] - PolyGamma[0, 1 + I a - x] + 
>   PolyGamma[0, -I a + x] - PolyGamma[0, I a + x])
> ```

Apparently there is something wrong here. Could anybody help me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localised, and unlikely to help future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

It is the same.  On V11.0.1, I do not get those PolyGamma though. Here is what I get

```
ClearAll[a,x,n]
r1=Sum[1/((x+n)^2+a^2),{n,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
factor=a;
r2=Sum[factor/((x+n)^2+a^2),{n,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(r2/factor-r1)//Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks!, I used V8. After changing to V11, it works well. Your answer is really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(*  "11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 21, 2016)"  *)
```

Your second stated result is

```
sol2 = 1/2 I (PolyGamma[0, 1 - I a - x] - PolyGamma[0, 1 + I a - x] + 
     PolyGamma[0, -I a + x] - PolyGamma[0, I a + x]);
```

With my version and OS

```
sol2a = Sum[a/((x + n)^2 + a^2), {n, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(*  1/2 (π Coth[a π - I π x] + π Coth[a π + I π x])  *)
```

Demonstrating that these are equivalent

```
sol2 == sol2a // FullSimplify

(*  True  *)
```

For real `a` and `x` the resulting form for `sol2 or sol2a` is close to your first result (call it sol1)

```
sol2a // ComplexExpand

(*  -((π Sinh[2 a π])/(Cos[2 π x] - Cosh[2 a π]))  *)

sol1 = Sum[1/((x + n)^2 + a^2), {n, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(*  (π Sinh[2 a π])/(a (-Cos[2 π x] + Cosh[2 a π]))  *)
```

However, even without the restriction to reals

```
sol2a/sol1 // Simplify

(*  a  *)
```